# Laravel Mail Not Sending Via Queue

Tags: php, email, laravel, queue

I just set up a beanstalkd / supervisor config on my server. The queues are working, but when I try and use Laravel's Mail function in conjunction, the emails are not sending.

I do use gmail for sending out mails, which has not been an issue when using Mail::send in my other normal code. It seems to only not send when I try via a queue.

Route:

```
Route::get('/', function() {

  $test = "my name";

  Queue::push('DuplicateAccount', $test);  

});
```

Class:

```
class DuplicateAccount {

  public static function fire($job, $data) {

    self::send($data);

    $job->delete();

  }

  public static function send($data) {

    $admin = 'MyEmail';

    Mail::send('emails.admin.duplicate', array('duplicate'=>$data), function($message) use ($admin) {
      $message->to($admin, 'MyName')->subject('Subscription Duplicate');
    });

    Log::info('a. Mail '.$data.' to '.$admin.'.');

  }

}
```

Comment: What is the error ? You may simply use `Mail::queue('emails.welcome', $data, function($message){...});` as well [Check Here](http://laravel.com/docs/mail#queueing-mail).

Comment: I def tried to just use the Mail::queue as well, but still nothing sends. Mail::send works, but is really bad to use when batch sending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an issue with my mail driver settings apparently. Most likely an issue with gmail and my php.ini configuration when handling the serialization of the queue'd emails.

I changed to smtp and it started to work.

Comment: can you please mention which line of `php.ini` file ? 
because I'm not been able to access user model in mail template. I've to paas data separately.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start Queue Listener

`php artisan queue:listen`

please visit the link(http://laravel.com/docs/queues#running-the-queue-listener)

Comment: Sorry I already have this set up. There was an issue with the mail driver apparently. I changed to smtp and it works.